# Strange NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

I have strange problem...

My file strings.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?>
<resources>
    <string name="building_name">My House</string>
</resources>
```

Well, my R contains:

```
[...]
public static final class String {
    public static final int building_name=0x7f02383;
}
[...]
```

So, when I try to call this String in my code like this:

```
private final String BUILDING_NAME = getString(R.string.building_name);
```

I have this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instanciate activity ComponentInfo{...}:          java.lang.NullPointerException
{...}
  caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

at {the line where I instanciate the building_name}

What's wrong with my code?Please help

Comment: Did you import your R class, not android.R class?

Comment: It's OK I found the solution, thank you! (look at the other answers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't call `getString` before your Activity has been initialized. That's because `getString` is the same as `context.getResources().getString()`. And context is not initialized.

So basically, you can not assign value to static variables in this way.

But there is a way to use resource strings in your static variables. For this create your application (see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)) and then retrieve context from there. Here is a short example:

```
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <application  android:name="com.mypackage.MyApplication" ... >
       ...
    </application>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Then create `MyApplication.java` file:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{   
    private static MyApplication s_instance;

    public MyApplication ()
    {
        s_instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext()
    {
        return s_instance;
    }

    public static String getString(int resId)
    {
        return getContext().getString(resId);       
    }
}
```

And then use it to get string resource:

```
private final String BUILDING_NAME = MyApplication.getString(R.string.building_name);
```

You can even do this fir static fields.

Comment: +1, awesome - I got a version of this error myself. Great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Using this might help you

```
getResources().getString(R.string.building_name);
```

This works for me

Answer (score 2):

There are some cases where this happens, for the same you should try some steps mentioned below:

1. Try to clean your project.
2. Check whether the android.R class file is imported or not, if it is imported then remove it and import your R class file.
3. Try using getResources().getString(R.string.myString) method.

Answer (score 0):

if you have error in getting some text from one activity to another activity 
Like for example

```java
StudentID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Value");
```

getString giving null pointer exception then

that StudentID is of String type so just declare StudentID as

`private String StudentID;`