# java.lang.NullPointer Exception in getResources().getString(R.string.value);

Tags: java, android, xml

I want one constant value in all activities so I have written it in string.xml file.

Now, to get that value in .java file, I am writing code as below :

```
getResources().getString(R.string.my_website); - This is 18 line of Splash Class
```

**I am calling this code in main class as below :**

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
    final String WebsiteURL = getResources().getString(R.string.my_website);
}
```

but it is giving me `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Am I writing anything wrong?

This is the correlating **strings.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="my_website">http://www.mytestbuddy.com</string>
</resources>
```

**Logcat:**

```
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Mobile.mytestbuddy/com.Mobile.mytestbuddy.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at com.Mobile.mytestbuddy.Splash.<init>(Splash.java:18)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
01-30 17:57:15.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1553):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to fit your edits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your edits you're trying to access the resources before the Activity has been created. This is not possible, since the required `Context` is not available yet during that point.

You'll need to set your `websiteUrl` from within the `onCreate(...)` method.

--Old answer for reference--

```
 getResources().getString(R.string.my_website);
```

As you can see, `string` has to be written in lowercase. Also you should not be looking for an `Integer` but a `String`.

Comment: sorry for my mistake, but I am already writing string in lower case.

Comment: That's good. The app should not have been compiling if you used uppercase anyways. Nonetheless the question implied that this is part of the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

you must use

```
getResources().getString(R.string.my_website);
```

change `getInteger` with `getString` and `String` with `string` (lowercase `s`)

You can't call `getString` before your `Activity` has been initialized. That's because `getString` is the same as `context.getResources().getString()`. And `context` is not initialized

for more info please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261990/strange-nullpointerexception)

Comment: thank you. It was my mistake in post. I am writing getString but then also I am getting same error.

Comment: please clean your project and try again

Comment: getResources().getString(R.string.my_website); is the line of 18 of Splash class

Comment: Yes, I did it and run again. Even I close Emulator and started again but same error.

Comment: I am calling this in main class, check updated post.

Comment: see my Edit and check the link

Answer (score 0):

You need put  `getResources().getString(R.string.my_website);` after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to access the resources, because Activity need init.